# Grafana exclude values from query with wildcard

Tags: regex, grafana, graphite

I have a grafana query that sums a number of stats, my query looks like

```
alias(summarize(sumSeries(stats.checkout-*.*.*.*.*), '$time', 'sum', false), 'checkout')
```

The names from graphite are country based i.e.

```
stats.checkout-uk  

stats.checkout-es  

stats.checkout-it
```

This all works ok but I would now like to exclude a few countries from the results i.e. i don't want to include `stats.checkout-es` (there are maybe 3 or 4 I need to exclude). I don't want to manually write out the values for each country and somehow sum them together (seems the wrong way).

How can I exclude just certain names from the query whilst still using my wildcard ?

[grafana query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lz8wY.png)

Answer (score 1):

```
alias(summarize(sumSeries(exclude(stats.checkout-*.*.*.*.*),"checkout-es"), '$time', 'sum', false), 'checkout')
```

This should be work.

https://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/functions.html#graphite.render.functions.exclude

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need alerts you could use transformations

Filter data by name
Filter data by query
Filter data by value

https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/panels/transformations/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).